# Creating and theming ExtJS 6 component

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I`m trying to create a custom component for my ExtJS application (using extjs 6.0 and modern toolkit)

I`ve generated a new app and added a new View (extending Ext.Component), put some logic there. I am able to create this component with xtype but get stuck with theming.

So the question is: how to add a new component correctly (inside framework source / as a view in the app / somewhere else) and where to put sass for the component (generate a custom theme and insert it there / somewhere else)?

Component (located in app/view/components folder):

```
Ext.define("WebTest.view.components.IconButton", {
extend: 'Ext.Component',
xtype: 'iconbutton',

cachedConfig: {
    pressedCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'iconbutton-pressing',
    iconCls: null
},

config: {
    handler: null,
    scope: null,
    baseCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'iconbutton' + ' ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'iconalign-center'
},

template: [
    {
        tag: 'span',
        className: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'iconbutton-icon',
        reference: 'iconElement'
    }
],
............
```

ADDED:

I have tried different methods of adding component and theme (the goal is to change standard CSS and add custom).

Acceptable way (for me) is to put the custom component into `ux.button folder` (as @Alexander mentioned) and to *generate* a new *theme*. Because of usage of two (in my case) different namespaces there is a need to clear *namespace* parameter in themes *package.json*. This gives an opportunity to add custom styles to `src\MyAppNs\...\MyComponentClassName.scss` and also add or override for standard components (i.e. `var\Ext\Component.scss`)

Also tried to use *workspace*, but this way is better for sharing components and themes between several applications. In this case component could be added as a package (like theme in the first way).

Finally, tried to add custom component to the *framework source*, but noticed that SenchaCMD does not support acting this way. Think, that it is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you want to add the component under `Ext` or under `<YourAppNamespace>` is up to you. You could even create a special lib namespace for your custom component library.

I would recommend to name the component `<Namespace>.ux.button.IconButton`.

The styles for `<YourAppNamespace>.ux.button.IconButton` go into `sass/src/ux/button/IconButton.sass`, the styles for `Ext.ux.button.IconButton` into `ext/modern/your-selected-theme/sass/src/ux/button/IconButton.sass`.

I did not yet try to use a lib namespace and don't know where to put the CSS for that.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have updated the question with some research results. Your answer helped me.